# Different names for man

Tags: names, adam

What is the difference between the Hebrew words 'adam', 'ish' and 'enosh'? In Genesis, the word adam is used until the woman is brought to him and then he calls her 'Ishah' and refers to himself as 'Ish'. In Psalm 49;2 it refers to the sons of Adam and the sons of Ish. Who would then be the sons of Ish? Why this distinction? And in Genesis 18;16 the angels that visited Abraham are referred to as enosh in this verse.

Answer (score 1):

The Torah generally uses 4 names for mankind, and *Adam* is the highest. There are 3 others that are gradually lower in stature (and therefore less of a compliment!):

- *Ish*
- *Gever*
- *Enosh*

The Alter Rebbe explains that *Adam* is the highest (it is based on the fact that it is similar to the hebrew word "*adame*" which means "similar to [God]" and sometimes represents mankind in relation to his or her intellect), whereas *Ish* is lower (and conotes the emotions). Still, these two terms are lofty terms referring to mankind as a lofty entity in or even the pinnacle of creation.

Rabbi Yosef Yitzchak Schneersohn explains that *gever* means a man who is accomplishing his tasks, a man of strength and mastery, but not in a spiritual sense, so this term is not a very lofty one. An *enosh* literally just means "mortal", someone whose biggest compliment is that they are alive... otherwise they are not contributing very much.

He also explains that *Adam* is indeed the pinncale of creation, in that he can relate to God better than angels, even the most lofty of angels, who - in their raw abstract intellects - are unable to conceive of a dwelling place for Hashem in a time bound, space bound, physical reality. Only *Adam* is able to conceive of this and make it happen.

---

The Zohar (III, 48a) explains that *Adam* represents the complete human being, male and female (so it can be used to describe man before Hashem split them, or a married couple who have achieved true intimacy). Once they are split apart, they are referred to as *Ish* and *Isha*.

---

I will see if I can find an answer as to why the angels are called *enosh.* That (and the rest) is a great question! Maybe it's because they were being described how they were meant to look - like vagabonds.

Comment: Ish and Isha are referring to husband and wife specifically. The delineations you bring from the Alter Rebbe are related to variations in the human species…and Shavuah tov my friend!

Comment: @YaacovDeane shana tova! Yes, I read your answer where you brought these details in full, feel free to link it. It is definitely interesting, if a tad controversial :)

Comment: I hope you’re proceeding toward a wonderful Shabbat and first days of the Chag. I was reflecting on your comment above that you felt what I was explaining was “controversial”. Assuming that you daven from the Alter Rebbe’s nusach, do you also think his nusach of אלו דברים שאין להם שעור כו׳ at the close of morning blessings is also “controversial”? (Specifically his addition to the text of Shabbat 127a) Most people read שבין אדם לחברו ובין איש ואשתו as a single category. But it actually means בין אדם לחברו and בין אדם למקום. That יהוה איש מלחמה (Shemot 15:3) and Israel is His wife.

Comment: @YaacovDeane I don't daven that nusach (I daven sefardi), but you are making me wish I did, that's stunning, thanks for sharing and enhancing my Yom Tov :) I don't know if that is controversial, just the idea that there were variations in human species doesn't seem to be widely accepted, in my experience. Chag samayach my friend

Comment: See Sefer HaChinuch 239:1 in regard to this dimension and also Kli Yakar to Devarim 31:1:4.

Comment: Regarding species of humans, the genetic reality cannot be denied and the many sources I brought demonstrate that the traditional Torah view clearly states what we observe in the physical, bio-chemical, genetic reality. It’s not a chiddush at all. It’s just that this generation is, for the most part, unaware that the Torah actually says this.

Comment: @YaacovDeane it's an excellent presentation and proof, please link it.

Comment: Regarding your thought about the connection between Enosh and Angels, the generation of Enosh was when people began to worship stars and constellations, like is mentioned by Rambam in Hilchot Avodah Zarah & also Sefer Brit Menucha. They were worshipping the angels assigned to those heavenly bodies. It is a mistake intellectually. That is in keeping with the previous Rebbe’s explanation.

Comment: The Adam concept is completion and perfection both physically/emotionally and mentally. The דומה לעליון idea is referring to the nature of that perfection, referring to G-d’s 6 letter name. See Rabbi Menachem Azaryeh of Fano, מאמר אם כל חי, section 3. This is also in keeping with Reishit Chochmah by Rabbi Eliyahu de Vidas.

Comment: You might want to source the section from HaYom Yom that actually discusses all this.

Comment: Gut Moed my friend. As I was reviewing the teachings of the Ba’al Shem Tov (the Chassidic Ushpiz for the first night of Sukkot) from Sefer Keter Shem Tov as published by Kehot, it came to my attention that in the very beginning of the book it lists the 4 directives of the Ba’al Shem Tov. The 4th directive, which is emphasizing the importance of keeping Shabbat according to all the details, brings the same idea mentioned above how it was in the generation of Enosh that people began to make the mistake about idol worship, that they called אל, אליל. That keeping Shabbat is the Tikkun.

Comment: The previous Rebbe uses the term איש-גבר, that the term איש refers to an individual who is גובר על מדותיו, he overpowers and controls his emotions.